# print values from a list in vertical order for many lists

Tags: python-3.x

I'm having trouble printing data from a list vertically , the list is as shown below

```
[[1, 4, 5], [4, 6, 8], [8, 3, 10]]
```

I want to print the data into a new list as follows:

```
[[1, 4, 8], [4, 6, 3], [5, 8, 10]]
```

I'm having trouble doing it when the lists get longer, as it is a nested list

Comment: What have you tried, which set of data gave you a problem with that approach?

Comment: Is the data only numbers / integers?

Comment: I think you had an error with your input. I made the correction. Let me know if I got it right.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for `zip`.

```
l = [[1, 4, 5], [4, 6, 8], [8, 3, 10]]
z = zip(*l)
print('\n'.join(map(str, z)))   
# Output is: 
# (1, 4, 8)
# (4, 6, 3)
# (5, 8, 10)
```

It does produce tuples instead of lists, but that is usually easily dealt with, and if you are just iterating over them, then it probably doesn't matter.

```
l = [[1, 4, 5], [4, 6, 8], [8, 3, 10]]
z = map(list, zip(*l))
print('\n'.join(map(str, z)))
```

Will give you the same result, but will print them out as lists.

Comment: This doesnt solve what the OP is asking for. His issue is related to printing the data, not the datatype. Using zip doesnt change how `l` is printed

Comment: They said: "So I want to print the data into a new list like [1,4,8] as one list and the next list as [2,6,3] etc but I'm having trouble doing it when the lists get longer, as it is a nested list".  I took that to mean, the challenging thing part was getting them into the appropriate lists.  But sure...I can add a '\n'.join() to the example.

Answer (score 1):

If the data is only numbers / integers, then you might want to use numpy for this. It will be faster too.

```py
import numpy
givenList = [[1, 4, 5], [4, 6, 8], [8, 3, 10]]
toNumpy = numpy.array(givenList) #convert to numpy array
toNumpy = toNumpy.T #transpose
toList = toNumpy.tolist() #convert back to list
print(toList)
# output : [[1, 4, 8], [4, 6, 3], [5, 8, 10]]
```